# Date parse exception while creating object from json string

Tags: java, datetime

I am using jersey for creating RestAPI and JPA2.0

I have one API which reads the data from DB and send it to UI. Return data is in the form of JSON. It has one field for date time which is getting the below value from DB
“updateDateTime”:”2016-07-01 14:15:55.0”

The UI reads this value from JSON and send it in the same format to another API which while parsing this date throws exception as

java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2016-07-01 14:15:55.0"

This exception is coming when I am converting json string to object

Comment: And the Problem is?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I am getting “2016-06-22 16:17:03.0” from DB and sending it to UI in JSON, UI send it to other API which was throwing date parsing exception while converting to object

I have tried various date formats like 
SimpleDateFormat resultDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss");
SimpleDateFormat dbDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");

After trying different pwrmutation and combinations I gave and asked the question in stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to parse it into date and then back to String:

```
    DateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"),
            formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss aaa");
    Date date = parser.parse("2016-06-22 16:17:03.0");
    String toData = formatter.format(date);
```

The above code will output: `Jun 22, 2016 04:17:03 PM`
Your code will have to handle `java.text.ParseException`

Comment: Thanks Ernest, I am able to solve my problem, the second date format was the answer that I was looking for.